# Bluemix iOS bluelist quick start

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

When building the bms-samples-ios-bluelist which has the quickstart BlueList app, no matter whether I choose FaceBook or Google Authentication, the apps hangs with a Facebook Login or a Google Login prompt.

I get no error messages.

And by tracing I see it does execute 
`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and
`applicationDidBecomeActive` Methods.

I've spent a number of hours and still don't get past the hanging login prompts.

Would anyone have any clues?

From the Xcode console there are just some NSLogs i.e.

```
2015-11-03 09:29:22.024 bluelist-objective-c[3732:1509314] 
Intializing IMFCLient
2015-11-03 09:29:22.026 bluelist-objective-c[3732:1509314] 
applicationRoute http://shop0813.bluecend.com/
2015-11-03 09:29:22.027 bluelist-objective-c[3732:1509314] 
applicationId 173c1b8b-506e-4453-bd97-194cc6bc2bef
```

And, I trace the code but it never crashes on anything.

But, after

`cf logs shop0813`

I find:

```
2015-11-03T09:28:41.54-0600 [RTR/1]      OUT shop0813.bluecend.com - 
[03/11/2015:15:28:41 +0000] "PUT http://bluelist/enroll HTTP/1.1" 404 0 34 "-" 
"BlueListIDAgent/1 CFNetwork/758.1.6 Darwin/15.0.0" 
108.168.250.153:54267 x_forwarded_for:"67.198.78.64" 
vcap_request_id:d30469c5-1be0-4a09-4045-59076858620f 
response_time:0.007576638 app_id:173c1b8b-506e-4453-bd97-194cc6bc2bef
```

While trying to more log info as your instructed, I discovered while tracing

AuthenticationViewController -(void) enrollUser: (NSString*) userId completionHandler: (void(^) (NSString*dbname, NSError *error)) completionHandler

is trying to enroll the user via Facebook with

http://shop0813.bluecend.com//bluelist/enroll, and

the response is

404 i.e. file not found i.e.

{ URL: http://shop0813.bluecend.com//bluelist/enroll } { status code: 404, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 03 Nov 2015 19:45:59 GMT";
    "Set-Cookie" = "**VCAP_ID**=cacaa80c45c948199ca93135ae76986a8ef3000c8855481aa3afadaa33b67a6d; Path=/; HttpOnly";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Backside-Transport" = "FAIL FAIL";
    "X-Cf-Requestid" = "c70c0b0b-81c2-4eb9-417d-4221f2fb69ed";
    "X-Client-IP" = "67.198.78.64";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Global-Transaction-ID" = 2269523159;
    "X-Powered-By" = Express;
} }

I suspect the request is using the wrong url.

Comment: You should be able to see debug output in the Xcode console. Can you provide the output here? Also it may be helpful to look at the logs of your bluemix application as well.

Comment: i just added the debug / log output

Comment: Do you have the node.js application that is provided in the application deployed? Can you please provide the whole log for the device side and any more information from the Bluemix side. Also Bluemix has been having some issues this morning that may be causing delays.

Comment: As you suggested, I tried to get more logging info and discovered a 404 error which gives me something to pursue. : )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the enroll endpoint is 404ing because there's an extra '/' in the request.

Try removing the last '/' from your app route.

Change:

applicationRoute http://shop0813.bluecend.com/

to

applicationRoute http://shop0813.bluecend.com

and see if that works.

Comment: I just began to suspect that as well. But, it didn't resolve the 404. Here's the response showing the extra / is gone.

<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f814be5b2e0> { URL: http://shop0813.bluecend.com/bluelist/enroll } { status code: 404, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 03 Nov 2015 22:15:47 GMT";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Backside-Transport" = "FAIL FAIL";
    ...

Comment: You are missing the Node JS app then, as Josh mentions above

Comment: That makes sense. I will try that today.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have successfully deployed the Node.js application that was supplied in the sample to your Bluemix backend. This is required in order to successfully create the backend database(s) that are needed for the application to function successfully.

Instructions can be found in the [README](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-ios-bluelist/blob/master/README.md) under Deploy the Bluelist NodeJS application to Bluemix.

I can tell the node.js bluelist application is not currently running in your environment when attempting to access the following URL:

```
<APPLICATION_ROUTE>/bluelist/enroll
```

Currently when accessing your envrionment I see:

```
404 Not Found: Requested route ('<APPLICATION_ID>') does not exist.
```

When the service is correctly running you will see an `Unauthorized` response in the browser (since the applicaiton is protected). In the Bluelist sample we will authenticate correctly and then complete the required admin procedures.

Comment: That makes sense. I will try that today.